# The import org.apache.commons.lang3 compilation error

Tags: java

I am trying to change my Java code from commons.lang to commons.lang3. So I did the below changes to my code and try to build it. But I am getting an error message. It would be great if someone can guide me on the way I need to change the code and about the jar I need to download.

before code

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils"%>

firstname = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(user.getFirstName());
```

Code change to add lang3

```
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils"%>

firstname = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(user.getFirstName());
```

Now I am getting below error

```
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: jspc failed with errors :weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: studentData.jsp:7:18: The import org.apache.commons.lang3 cannot be resolved
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils"%>

                 ^----------------------------------------^
studentData.jsp:148:21: StringEscapeUtils cannot be resolved
                                                                firstname = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(user.getFirstName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your webapp has the correct commons-lang in WEB-INF/lib.
The file you need is part of https://dlcdn.apache.org//commons/lang/binaries/commons-lang3-3.12.0-bin.zip and has the name `commons-lang3-3.12.jar`. In case you have an older version of commons-lang still in that folder, remove it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I used commons-lang3-3.12.jar but its not working. This is a JSP page. So do I need to change this to org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils

Comment: I just checked the jar file and it contains the class, so your import short not be a problem. Either you do not have it in your webapp when the JSP is compiled, or you are facing some other problem.